# Set different URLs using group box

Tags: c#, visual-studio, select, authentication, server

I have 3 connection servers, example:

```
 adm.login.com
 host.login.com
 user.login.com
```

How can I choose through a groupbox which server will be used for connection?

```
if (comboBox1.Text == "1") {
    server =  "adm.login.com";
}
if (comboBox1.Text == "2") {
    server = "host.login.com";
}
if (comboBox1.Text == "3") {
    server = "users.login.com";
}

string s;
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://" + server);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you declare an array parallel to the links.
Then call the Selected Index of the combo box against the array.

example:

```
string[] servers = new string[] {"adm.login.com","host.login.com", "user.login.com" };
Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://" +servers[combobox1.SelectedIndex]);
```